# Unable to install DFINITY Canister SDK on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dfinity

I'm following the steps found [here](https://sdk.dfinity.org/docs/quickstart/quickstart.html#download-and-install) to install `DFINITY Canister SDK`.
When I run the below command, directory `dfx` (under `/bin`) is not created and subsequently the `dfx` command is not recognized:

```bsh
adel@adel-VirtualBox:~$ sh -ci "$(curl -fsSL https://sdk.dfinity.org/install.sh)"

info: Executing DFINITY SDK install script, commit: dd2134837704e0daca074dd3fe09ee4ff6ebbf97

 DFINITY SDK 
 Please READ the following license: 

DFINITY Foundation -- All rights reserved. This is an ALPHA version
of the DFINITY Canister Software Development Kit (SDK). Permission is hereby granted
to use AS IS and only subject to the Alpha DFINITY Canister SDK License Agreement which
can be found here [https://sdk.dfinity.org/sdk-license-agreement.txt]. It comes with NO WARRANTY.


Do you agree and wish to install the DFINITY ALPHA SDK [y/N]?
y

info: Version found: 0.6.10
info: Creating uninstall script in ~/.cache/dfinity
info: uninstall path=/home/adel/.cache/dfinity/uninstall.sh
info: Checking for latest release...
Will install in: /home/adel/bin
info: Installed /home/adel/bin/dfx

adel@adel-VirtualBox:~$ dfx --version

Command 'dfx' not found, did you mean:

  command 'fx' from snap fx (11.1.0)
  command 'dfix' from snap dfix (0.3.5)
  command 'dx' from deb dx (1:4.4.4-12build2)
  command 'dex' from deb dex (0.8.0-2)
  command 'dfc' from deb dfc (3.1.1-1)
  command 'df' from deb coreutils (8.30-3ubuntu2)

See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions.

adel@adel-VirtualBox:~$ cd /bin
adel@adel-VirtualBox:/bin$ cd dfx
bash: cd: dfx: No such file or directory
```

Below is my Ubuntu version:

```bsh
adel@adel-VirtualBox:~$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

From the output of the install command it looks as if dfx is installed in `/home/adel/bin/dfx`.  Can you verify that:

1. dfx is indeed there?

```
test -e /home/adel/bin/dfx && echo yay found it || echo oh no
```

If not, it looks as if the install didn't work.

If yes, you can run it directly:

```
"$HOME/bin/dfx" --version
```

2. Check that your path includes "/home/adel/bin"

```
echo "$PATH" | tr : "\n" | grep "$HOME/bin"
```

If not, you can add it with:

```
echo 'export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/bin"' >> "$HOME/.bashrc"

. "$HOME/.bashrc"

dfx --version
```

Comment: Max, like I mentioned in my post; nothing gets created, I should have been more detailed. I updated my post to clarify that directory `dfx` is not created; I also added the terminal output to show that.

Comment: I misunderstood the script logic and thought it will place the binary inside `~/bin/dfx` instead of `~/bin`. Now it all makes sense and works fine.

Answer (score 4):

when I used the command

```
dfx --version
```

it didn't recognoze.

but when I used the complete path it worked.

```
sudo /home/osboxes/bin/dfx --version
```

*dfx 0.8.0*

Comment: Had to do same thing despite adding path.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem. For some reason there is a `~/bin` directory so first I delete it then follow the previous answer:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-158:~$ PATH=~/bin:$PATH
ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-158:~$ export PATH
ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-158:~$ sh -ci "$(curl -fsSL https://sdk.dfinity.org/install.sh)"
info: Executing dfx install script, commit: 0a3bd5b38e498f899c8074d734116c10e0e53ca5
info: Version found: 0.8.3
info: Creating uninstall script in ~/.cache/dfinity
info: uninstall path=/home/ubuntu/.cache/dfinity/uninstall.sh
info: Checking for latest release...
Will install in: /home/ubuntu/bin
info: Installed /home/ubuntu/bin/dfx
ubuntu@ip-172-31-81-158:~$ dfx --version
dfx 0.8.3
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30351770)

Answer (score 0):

you need to give it the path. run the code below and make sure to place the binary inside ~/bin instead of ~/bin/dfx

```
export PATH=$PATH:<REPLACE WITH YOUR INSTALLATION PATH>
```

you got your installation path at the bottom when you installed dfx
[where you find the ringt installion path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc2LB.png)

Answer (score 0):

**After installing DFX** add your installed path on this line 
$ export PATH=$PATH:

Check that it has been added by running:
echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"

Finally, **restart Ubuntu again & run dfx --version it will definitely work and show you the current dfx version 0.11.0**

Answer (score 0):

**Issue**
I faced below issue even after exporting path as mentioned below.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/*****/bin/dfx
```

Faced the same issue:

```
dfx --version
Command 'dfx' not found, did you mean:
  command 'fx' from snap fx (24.1.0)
  command 'dfix' from snap dfix (0.3.5)
  command 'dex' from deb dex (0.9.0-1)
  command 'dx' from deb dx (1:4.4.4-15)
  command 'dfc' from deb dfc (3.1.1-1)
  command 'df' from deb coreutils (8.32-4.1ubuntu1)
See 'snap info <snapname>' for additional versions
```

**Solution**

as mentioned above run the command after mentioning the path:

```
sudo /home/osboxes/bin/dfx --version
```

To find the path run the command

```
echo "${PATH//:/$'\n'}"
```

---

To resolve all issues: I strongly recommends follow most voted ans. line of code.

because for me `dfx new my_app` was not working but it worked after I ran below line of codes.

1. `test -e /home/navalega0109/bin/dfx && echo yay found it || echo oh no`
2. `"$HOME/bin/dfx" --version`
3. `echo "$PATH" | tr : "\n" | grep "$HOME/bin"`

Answer (score 0):

After installed on my local I got this message:

```
dfx-0.14.3-x86_64-linux.tar.gz: OK
Will install in: /home/akhisyabab/bin
info: Installed /home/akhisyabab/bin/dfx
```

in official documentation of IC, dfx should be located at /usr/local/bin/dfx, So I just link the location

```
sudo ln -s /home/akhisyabab/bin/dfx /usr/local/bin/dfx
```

It works for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will work once you restart Ubuntu

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34859193)

Answer (score 0):

The export command you provided appends the `/home/adel/bin/dfx` directory to the end of the existing `PATH` variable. However, there's a common misunderstanding in your export command. You should include only the directory path in the `PATH` variable, not the full path to the executable (`/home/adel/bin/dfx`).

Here's the correct `export` command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/adel/bin
```

This command adds the `/home/adel/bin` directory to the end of the `PATH` variable. After making this change, you should be able to run `dfx` from any directory in your terminal.

After modifying the `PATH`, either restart your terminal session or run the following command to apply the changes:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Now, you should be able to execute the `dfx` command without specifying the full path:

dfx

Make sure that the `dfx` executable has the execute permission (`chmod +x /home/adel/bin/dfx`) and that the `dfx` binary is indeed located in the specified directory. If the issue persists, you might also want to check for any aliases or functions that might affect the command resolution.